# Fatal error: Can't write file style related file

Tags: bibliographies, miktex, glossaries

I am using a custom documentclass, which uses a couple `.sty` files. I get the following fatal error:

```
Line 480 I can't write on file `Main.cb'. ...ediate\openout\cb@write=\jobname.cb\relax
```

Line 480 contains the following code:

```
\immediate\openout\cb@write=\jobname.cb\relax
```

This content is placed in the file `changebar.sty`, which is included and used by the documentclass.

My report used to compile, however, I've updated MiKTex and TexStudio (multiple times) and since then I get the fatal error I wrote above.

I use the newest versions of both TeXstudio 2.10.4 and Basic MikTex 2.9.5671 on a Windows 7 home premium laptop . I have updated MiKTex twice so that no updates are available anymore.

I have compiled the document on another Linux computer and there it worked. So I guess it had something to do with my software? I fixed this error by changing the name of the main tex file. Now I got errors on my glossaries, which used to work and my bibliography doesn't work anymore.

I get the following errors:

```
Command \@printglossary already defined. 
Use of \@printglossary doesn't match its definition. ...ctitle=List of Abbreviations,nonumberlist]
Too many }'s. ...ctitle=List of Abbreviations,nonumberlist]
The `cite' package should not be used(natbib) with natbib. Use option `sort' instead.
```

And I get a warning that it cannot find the `.acr` file. The code of my main file is:

```
\documentclass[]{FlightDynamics}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref} % jabref
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[round]{natbib} % round brackets citep
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % Centered column

\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{rotating} % Sideways figure

% Figures
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\include{Acronyms}

\include{Preface}
\include{Abstract}

\tableofcontents

\glossarystyle{super}
\printglossary[title=List of Abbreviations,toctitle=List of Abbreviations,nonumberlist]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
\mainmatter

% Chapters
\include{Introduction}

%Bibliography
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{authordate1} % authordate1
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

I also tried perl to run `makeglossaries` but it didn't work.

All these things used to work until I updated the software..

Any ideas? Or do you see any clear mistakes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Probably not the cause of your problem, but `hyperref` and `glossaries` should be the last packages being included. Since we don't know `FlightDynamics.cls` it's quite difficult to tell.

Comment: I have a similar problem that happens with certain files  since last MiKTeX's update (yesterday): `can't write on the .aux file`.

Comment: The bug has already been discussed on the mailing list. It seems to be related to the length of the file name. Files with 4, 9, 14, 18 char fail (main has 4 chars). Rename your file

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I indeed renamed the file and I don't get the can't write errors anymore. However, it still doesn't create an .acr file and perl doesn't create a glossary anymore. Normally I run the file, then run perl to update the glossary and the document works. In addition, all my citations don't work and my bibliography won't show up.

Comment: I'm guessing that your definitions (`\newacronym` etc) are in the file `Acronyms.tex`. If so remove `\include{Acronyms}` and put `\loadglsentries{Acronyms}` in the preamble. See [Why shouldn't I use \include to include my glossary definitions?](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#include).

Comment: I tried the \loadglsentries and now i get an .acn file. However, my bibliography and citations still don't work. Does somebody know of a software update that messes up natbib or the glossaries package? Or a way how I could've messed the software up.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal example that we can actually test. We don't have the files you have included in your sample or the class file, so we can't reproduce the problem. Remove each package from your test file that doesn't contribute to the problem and provide minimal versions of `Acronyms.tex` etc. (You need to use @ in your comments to notify the user you're replying to, otherwise people may not notice your comment, especially after the question has dropped off the main page.)